# How can I configure @typescript-eslint/no-unused-vars to not flag vars in declaration files?

Tags: typescript, eslint

```
declare module "foo" {
    export const Foo = (props: string) => string;
}
```

The above snippet is an example of a type declaration, ie the contents of a .d.ts file. My issue is that if I run eslint over this file, `@typescript-eslint/no-unused-vars` will complain that the "props" variable is unused. TypeScript requires that I provide some name for the parameter in the declaration, but no implementation will ever be provided. Basically, this will never be used.

I can disable the rule for this file, but that seems like a blunt instrument. I'm wondering if there are any better solutions for this?

Comment: I think you need to use the word "type" instead of "const", it seems to me here you are exporting an actual function so this is not a type declaration at all.

Answer (score -1):

In your `.eslintrc.json` file you can specify which rules apply to which files

```
{
  "root": true,
  "ignorePatterns": [],
  "overrides": [
    {
      "files": ["*.ts"],
      "parserOptions": {
        "project": ["tsconfig.json"]
      },
      "plugins": [],
      "extends": [
        "eslint:recommended",
      ],
      "rules": {
        // your default rules here
      }
    },
    {
      "files": ["*.d.ts"],
      "rules": {
        // Everything from *.ts rules above applies
        // but you can add or override individual rules here for *.d.ts files
        "no-unused-vars": "off"
      }
    },
    {
      "files": ["*.spec.ts"],
      "rules": {
        // Everything from *.ts rules above applies
        // but you can add or override individual rules here for *.spec.ts files
      }
    }
  ]
}
```